# unknown: mosca in in Node-RED on IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I followed the instructions on http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/install-mosca-mqtt-broker-node-red/ on IBM Cloud.

I installed the node-red-contrib-mqtt-broker, but got the error "unknown: mosca in".
[image]

Installation error in app log:
[image]

Comment: That means the mosca node is not installed. Were there any errors when you installed it? And has the Node-RED instance been restaged since you installed it?

Comment: added the app log. I did not restage the app.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so as the log states, Node-RED has been unable to install the node.

Your best bet is to edit the `package.json` for the app so it is installed during app staging then restage the app. The easiest way to do this is to enable continuous integration for your app. I've not used IBM-Cloud in a while, so you'll have to check the docs for how to do this.

It's probably also worth noting that you will not be able to access the MQTT broker from outside Node-RED when running the mosca node on IBM-Cloud. This is because the IBM-Cloud environment only exposes one port from any application. In Node-RED's case this is the HTTP port.

Comment: Not sure if I should do this as I'm not a real developer and only want to use the GUI, otherwise it's a bug, I think.

Comment: You can raise an issue on github or bring it up on Slack if you want